# TypeScript Promise Syntax

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, promise

I've recently started studying about TypeScript, and came across the [Starter Project](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter) from the docs. Everything looks pretty straight forward, but there is one little part of the code that I just couldn't understand.

Here it is:

```js
// Connect to MongoDB
const mongoUrl = MONGODB_URI;
(<any>mongoose).Promise = bluebird;
mongoose.connect(mongoUrl).then(
  () => {},
).catch(err => {
  console.log("MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDB is running. " + err);
});
```

And the confusing part to me is this line:

```js
(<any>mongoose).Promise = bluebird;
```

The  `<any>mongoose` syntax remembers me of a type casting, but I don't think that is what is really happening here, since we have the `bluebird` module assigned to the `.Promise` part.

So if anyone is able to clear this out, I'd appreciate it pretty much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<any>mongoose` is indeed type casting, albeit the old syntax. The more current form would be `(mongoose as any).Promise = bluebird`. It means that you take the reference to `mongoose` and ignore its actual type, and treat it as `any`.

This prevents compile-time errors from type mismatches with mongoose.

In general, you should not cast to `any`, and you should look into why that is required of you in this case and see if you can avoid it.

Comment: What about the `.Promise = bluebird` part? I know `bluebird` is a promises module, but what does this assignment means here?

Comment: My guess is that assigning bluebird to `mongoose.Promise` will cause Promise-returning functions and methods from mongoose to return instances of `bluebird` instead of instances of the native `Promise`. But you can easily look at the docs to verify this.